# Mysql charset per query possible?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

Let's say I have two tables encoded by different charsets: table A by utf8, table B by latin1.
To query data on table A, I would switch the connection charset to utf8; and to latin1 for table B.
So the scenario is:

```
set names utf8;
select * from A where ...;
set names latin1;
select * from B where ...;
```

My first question is that is there anyway to avoid using "set names..." all the time? Actually my two tables reside in two separate databases (but I simplified the situation to one database as above) and it is not convenient to convert the charset of one database to that of the other. Is there anything like:

```
select ... with connection charset utf8;
```

Thanks!

Comment: You really should flip it all to UTF-8 for consistency's sake. Switching encodings all the time is troublesome and prone to failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No but I don't get why you want to do this: you seem to consider the wrong charset (server-side instead client-side). Your columns, in MySQL, can have different charsets, this is not (really) a problem if you specify the charset your client (which is PHP here) is using (through a `SET NAMES`, or better, its PHP equivalent) ; MySQL will do the needed conversions between clients and the data it stores.

=> The only "SET NAMES" you need to do is to declare the charset your application is using.

Comment: Thanks but let's consider my situation:
I have two applications X and Y. X uses only B, while Y uses both A and B. But I can't change X (therefore can't change the charset of B to utf8). This leads to my above question!

Comment: Of course "SET NAMES" works well so far, but my question is if I can avoid switching the connection charset back and forth all the time.

Comment: You don't have to worry about MySQL server-side charset (you don't really have to know them): just do the "SET NAMES", once per application, and its done. You can still define a default charset in my.ini to avoid the "SET NAMES" but it's a bad idea: what will happen if you change of environment?

Comment: You are correct if everything is also correct. But actually, my table B is marked as latin1, but its data is in utf8 already (application X encodes data in utf8 before storing in B, and convert back to Unicode when getting data from B). Using "set names utf8" in Y will make MySQL converting data to utf8 a second time before sending to Y, because B just doesn't know that its data are already in utf8.